# print out data in the non-intersection for set <string> A, set<string>B

Tags: c++, set, set-intersection

If I have two sets of data

```
set<string> A;
set<string> B;
```

use set_intersection I am able to obtain the data in the intersection part for the two sets.

How do I print out the data in the non-intersection part for the set A and set B, respectively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`std::set_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) or [`std::set_symmetric_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_symmetric_difference), depending on your needs.

(I'm too tired/lazy to write an example, but hopefully it should be obvious once you've read the above links!)

Comment: set_difference will give you the results A+B-(AB), what's the way to get A-(AB) and B-(AB)? //(AB)=intersection...does that means the set_symmetric_difference?

Comment: @user1830108: That sounds like the description of set_symmetric_difference.  So you probably want set_difference.

Comment: Isn't the question to do with printing out data?

Comment: @PeterWood: On a second look, yes.  But I assume that the set operation is the tricky part...

Answer (score 1):

`set_symmetric_difference` puts the results into some iterable object.

So, you can copy values into an `ostream` by wrapping it with an `ostream_iterator`:

```
set<string> a;
set<string> b;

set_symmetric_difference(a.begin(), a.end(),
                         b.begin(), b.end(),
                         ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
```